# Xcode console empty after attaching to process

Tags: ios, xcode

I build an app to my iPhone, quit it, launch it again and then I succesfully Attach to Process in Xcode. Now I have a running Debug in the Log Navigator, but my console is just empty. Shouldn't I see all my usual console outputs there?

Comment: can you attach screenshot?

Comment: Try re-running the project once

Comment: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/AGKUcVW.png). Re-running gives same result.

Comment: I am having this same issue.  I upvoted, hoping someone will answer.  That being said, there is a workaround: open Organizer, show console for the device and you can see the console output there.

Comment: Restart Xcode , Product -> Clean  Try

Answer (score 4):

You can see the logs in Device logs. Open xcode Window-->Devices (Select device)-->Device logs.Click on 'up' arrow button to see the consol.It display every logs in development/adhoc/appstore apps.

Answer (score 0):

The console in Xcode will only display output from your application's process, not the firehose of output shown in the general device console.

Comment: Sure, but mine shows nothing after attaching to process.

Answer (score 0):

I too face this problem recently and found it working when I force quit xcode and try clean build. Its adhock but it works. Have fun.

Answer (score -4):

check if you changed the bottom-left parameter of the XCode console

try selecting the default value "All Output"

[image]