# Xcode attach to process doesn't display NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-watch

I'm just getting started with Apple Watch. I found instructions from "[**Five Minute Watchkit**](http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/?category=Xcode)", on getting the iOS app and the watch kit app both running in the simulator and both processes attached to the LLDB debugger.

What I do is launch and quit the iOS app to install a current version in the sim. Then I switch to the watchKit scheme and launch that, which displays my watch app UI on the watch simulator.

I then launch the corresponding iOS app in the simulator, then user "attach to process" in the Xcode menu to attach the debugger to the running iOS app.

This works. I can set breakpoints in either the watch kit InterfaceController or in my iOS app and the debugger breaks there when it should.

However, I'm not seeing NSLog() statements in the debug console from my iOS app. (I do see log statements from the WatchKit extension code.) If I set a breakpoint in my iOS app, it does stop at that breakpoint when it should. I assume the lack of console output from NSLog has SOMETHING to do with attaching to a running process on the sim rather than launching it from Xcode, but I don't know what that something is.

(BTW, attaching an action to a breakpoint that invokes NSLog from the breakpoint also doesn't display, but the "log message" debugger command DOES display.
Does anybody have any insights?)

EDIT: 
The code in the iOS app doesn't seem to matter. In my case, it was a dirt simple IBAction that was attached to a button in the iOS app storyboard:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender;
{
  NSLog(@"Button clicked on iPhone");
}
```

I can set a breakpoint on that NSLog statement. The debugger stops at that line, but I don't see the log statement in the debug console.

Comment: are you sure the compiler gets this far? oh and please show some code, that'd be helpful

Comment: Linus, I'm postive. The debugger breaks at the line containing the NSLog. It's just that the log statement does not get displayed to the console.

Comment: did you double-check that the connection is correct? try to use `id` instead of `UIButton`, maybe that helps

Comment: For the third time, the debugger stops at a breakpoint at the line in question. I am absolutely, 100%, dead certain that the connection is correct. The log statement works if I launch the iOS app using ⌘R in Xcode. It's only when I run the app in the sim and then attach to the running process that my NSLog statements fail to show.

Comment: Changing the IBAction's parameter type to id is waving a dead chicken at the problem, and is not even worth trying.

Comment: [**Waving a Dead Chicken Over a Problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waving_a_dead_chicken_(over_it))

Comment: here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277804/ios-iphone-ipad-ipodtouch-view-real-time-console-log-terminal#28582642) talking about the solutions you can find. the first is [deviceconsole](https://github.com/onezens/deviceconsole) and a better one named [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) all in console, that allow you to filter to your needs

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I can reproduce that with a simple test app, sans WatchKit. The app consists of a NSTimer that prints "Timer fired" every second. (This code is 100% correct ;). Nothing shows in the log after I have manually attached to the process.
As far as I know NSLog outputs to stderr, I guess attaching the debugger does not redirect stderr to the Xcode terminal.

If you are okay with using the console app or the terminal to look at your logs you can do that. iOS8 stores simulator logs in `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/<Device-UUID>`. In this directory you will find a system.log, which contains all your `NSLog` output.

You can look at it in terminal (`cat`, `grep`, `tail`), or open it in the Console.app.

[image]

---

Apple confirms that (at least for GDB) in [Technical Note TN2239: iOS Debugging Magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html).

> Console Output
>
> Many programs, and indeed many system frameworks, print debugging
>   messages to stderr. The destination for this output is ultimately
>   controlled by the program: it can redirect stderr to whatever
>   destination it chooses. However, in most cases a program does not
>   redirect stderr, so the output goes to the default destination
>   inherited by the program from its launch environment. This is
>   typically one of the following:
>
> - If you launch a GUI application as it would be launched by a normal
>     user, the system redirects any messages printed on stderr to the
>     system log. You can view these messages using the techniques described
>     earlier.
> - If you run a program from within Xcode, you can see its
>     stderr output in Xcode's debugger Console window (choose the Console
>     menu item from the Run menu to see this window).
>
> **Attaching to a
>   running program (using Xcode's Attach to Process menu, or the attach
>   command in GDB) does not automatically connect the program's stderr to
>   your GDB window.** You can do this from within GDB using the trick
>   described in the "Seeing stdout and stderr After Attaching" section of
>   Technical Note TN2030, 'GDB for MacsBug Veterans'.

The mentioned TN2030 is no longer available on their server ([mirror](http://www.fenestrated.net/~macman/mirrors/Apple%20Technotes%20(As%20of%202002)/tn/tn2030.html)). It showed how you can redirect stdout and stderr to the Xcode console. However, since `shell tty` isn't a valid command for LLDB it won't help much. But maybe there is a different way to access the tty Xcodes console uses, so I attach the important part of that TN.

> Seeing stdout and stderr After Attaching
>
> If you attach GDB to a process (as opposed to starting the process
>   from within GDB), you won't be able to see anything that the process
>   prints to stdout or stderr. Programs launched by the Finder typically
>   have stdout and stderr connected to "/dev/console", so the information
>   they print goes to the console. You can view this by launching the
>   Console application (in the Utilities folder), however, it's
>   inconvenient to have to look in a separate window. Another alternative
>   is to connect the process's stdout or stderr to the terminal device
>   for GDB's Terminal window. Listing 9 shows how to do this.
>
> Listing 9. Connecting stdout and stderr to GDB's terminal device.
>
> ```
> (gdb) attach 795
> [... output omitted ...]
> (gdb) call (void) DebugPrintMenuList()
>  No output )-:
>
>  Close the stdout and stderr file descriptors.
> (gdb) call (void) close(1)
> (gdb) call (void) close(2)
>
>  Determine the name of the terminal device for GDB itself.
> (gdb) shell tty
> /dev/ttyp1
>
>  Reopen stdout and stderr, but connected to GDB's terminal.
>  The function results should be 1 and 2; if not, something
>  is horribly wrong.
> (gdb) call (int) open("/dev/ttyp1", 2, 0)
> $1 = 1
> (gdb) call (int) open("/dev/ttyp1", 2, 0)
> $2 = 2
>
>  Try the DebugPrintMenuList again.
> (gdb) call (void) DebugPrintMenuList()
>  Yay output!
> Index MenuRef     ID  Title
> ----- ---------- ---- -----
> <regular menus>
> 00001 0x767725D3 -21629 Ed
> 00002 0x76772627 1128 <Apple>
> 00003 0x767726CF 1129 File
> 00004 0x76772567 1130 Edit
> [... remaining output omitted ...]
> ```

Comment: I'm "ok" looking at my log output in the console if I must, but it sucks. The console is very noisy. System processes are constantly posting messages that are meaningless to me to the console. Plus, the Xcode debug console is designed for this. It's supposed to show output from the running program. Launching apps is a multi-step process: Kill watch app, iOS app, build and run iOS app, kill it, launch watch app, launch iOS app in sim, attach debugger to iOS app. It's a pain, truth be told.

Comment: MacsBug?!? Oh man, that goes back a LOOOOONNNG Way. That was back when Macs used 68000 family processors. I used MacsBug on my Mac II in the late 80s and 90s.

Comment: I should add a note about this to the FMW post. :-)

Comment: I would add that it's easy to filter with grep as mentioned above to find just your debug messages, so you don't have that console noise.

Comment: This is a real confusing issue that I've been scouring the internet for all morning.  Every single explanation explodes into a completely irrelevant discussion.  This is the only relevant answer so far.  Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

To add onto Filipp Keks answer, here's a visual representation of a much much simpler way to do it than the accepted answer.

From Filipp Keks's answer:

1. Plug in the device and open Xcode
2. Choose Window -> Devices from the menu bar
3. Under the DEVICES section in the left column, choose the device
4. To see the device console, click the up-triangle at the bottom left of the right hand panel
5. Click the down arrow on the bottom right to save the console as a file"

This screenshot was taken in Xcode 7.3.1 of the Devices window.

[image]

Comment: I aprrove it works the same way for Xcode 8.3.3 for me. One must remember, that this is a full debug log, so all apps and services appear there and you will have to find ones from your process.

Comment: Well "simpler" if you could **filter** these logs.. but ATM(xcode 9.2) you can't do a thing with this UI. (at least in a live session). Anyway I found a  github project [deviceconsole](https://github.com/onezens/deviceconsole) that does the same in a shell, allowing you to filter as it should be (a bit unstable tho, got several crashes :( ) Is there anybody knowing a better project for that?

Answer (score 8):

With Xcode Version 7.2 and iOS 9.2 etc, I found the following works:

1. Kill both the phone app and watch apps
2. Select the Watch Extension Target and hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (build and run)
3. Select the Phone target and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Run without building)

In my case, I have both apps up in their simulators and get NSLog output for both. I don't need to attach separately. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll have to try this. Thanks for posting on a rather old thread.

Comment: when I do this it stops my watch app and the watch goes to home screen.

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html

1. Plug in the device and open Xcode
2. Choose Window -> Devices from the menu bar
3. Under the DEVICES section in the left column, choose the device
4. To see the device console, click the up-triangle at the bottom left of the right hand panel
5. Click the down arrow on the bottom right to save the console as a file

Answer (score 0):

When your Provisioning profile is set to AdHoc or Distribution then Xcode doesnot show log, you need set development to view log

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve showing up NSLog messages, but it might be helpful when debugging app started in background.

You can use the breakpoint feature that allows you to log messages.
The idea is to:

- Create a breakpoint with "Automatically continue after evaluating actions" checked
- add "Log message" action (you can also use expressions and print out values, for example: "Log message @variable@")
- Attach debugger using anticipated process name (XCode will wait for the process to start)
- Trigger app start.

Credits and details:
https://fluffy.es/how-to-debug-app-which-got-launched-push-notification/

Answer (score -1):

In my case a set Automatically to see NSLog, before don't show at all

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I came to this question, via this one ([Xcode console empty after attaching to process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431036/xcode-console-empty-after-attaching-to-process)) which is now closed.

My issue is that the **debug console in Xcode is showing nothing** (just an empty white box).

The solution for me is a tiny toggle at the bottom which changes between "variable view" and the actual debug console.

[image]