# NSLog not showing in handleWatchKitExtensionRequest, but breakpoints works

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch, nslog

I have done everything in this order:

1. Run watch app.
2. Open from the simulator you iOS app
3. Attach the debugger to the iOS app
4. Finally execute the code that calls `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` on your watch.

But when I call `openParentApplication:reply:` from watch app extension , all NSLog from `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` doesn't prints out to console.

Breakpoints in `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` works fine. That means app attached fine.

Watch app extension logs still works too.

Seems like debugger is redirecting all NSLogs somewhere else.

Comment: There are separate consoles for the app and extensions. There should be a selector above the console, or somewhere in the bottom pane.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite I know, second console appears and I can switch between those two, but iPhone console is still empty.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29106019/834998) has an answer that should help you. Looks like a bug in the toolchain.