# NSLog with framework on IOS simulator not working

Tags: xcode, simulator, nslog

I'm using Xcode 7. I'm unable to get NSLog to work when I attach to an app running on a simulator. It works fine if I run it normally. But if I start the app and then attach to it NSLog output doesn't appear in the console. I can set breakpoints, view variables, etc. Everything seems normal except NSLog. The console window is open and displays the (lldb) prompt when I stop at a breakpoint. I can enter the help command and see a list of lldb options.

The one post on stack overflow I found was this one:
[Xcode attach to process doesn't display NSLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106019/xcode-attach-to-process-doesnt-display-nslog/29107583#29107583)
I tried to use the techniques described but didn't have any luck. For instance, DebugPrintMenuList() is not available in LLDB.

Does anyone know how to enable NSLogging when attaching to an app running in the simulator?